# Passing string from Startup.cs method to database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, websocket

i have a problem i have my Websocket method in Startup.cs Class in my Asp.Net Core RC1 project.

```
    private async Task Echo(WebSocket webSocket)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
        var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
        string text = "";
        while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
        {
            await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
            result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
            {
                text += (char) buffer[i];
            }
            /*

             TODO: ADD {text} to Database

             */
            text = text ?? "";
        }
        await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
    }
```

And i need to pass variable text to my database via Entity Framework 7, but i have problem with that. How can I do that?

Comment: You should likely mention which database system you're using - there are generalised classes for such handling but it could still be clearer. And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've used interface to manage my database and myDBcontext.